# Docker closes STDIN despite "--interactive"

Tags: docker, stdin

I'm trying to detach and reattach to a Docker container started with `docker run` in foreground mode. The issue I'm seeing is that during the initial detach Docker closes STDIN unexpectedly.

Here's an example script:

`/tmp/echo.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  echo "Received: $line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"  

echo "STDIN closed"

while [ 1 ]; do
  echo "Still alive"
done
```

So in theory I do this:

```
# docker run -i --sig-proxy=false --name=test --volume=/tmp:/tmp debian /tmp/echo.sh
```

Then CTRL+C which ends the `docker run` command (the INT signal is not forwarded), then:

```
# docker attach --sig-proxy=false test
```

The issue I'm seeing is that closing the `docker run` command also closes STDIN. The container continues running and when using `docker attach` it just spams `Still alive`.

However, if I run the following, then STDIN is kept open:

```
docker run -di --sig-proxy=false --name=test --volume=/tmp:/tmp debian /tmp/echo.sh
```

I can then use `docker attach` as expected, close the `docker attach` process with CTRL+C and run it again with STDIN staying open the entire time.

How can I close the initial `docker run` command without closing STDIN and without starting in detached mode?

Comment: Is your problem not just about how to put this process in background instead of foreground. Try pressing ctrl+Z instead of ctrl+C

Comment: No, I'd like to completely close any processes I use to run/attach the container, then pick up from where I left off.